# Navigating to deep route not working in case of Angular application

Tags: azure-active-directory, angular9

I have a angular application with URL: https://abc.xyz.com hosted within Azure App Service. This has a backend API hosted using a separate Azure App Service and different URL: https://xxx.yyy.com. Both the endpoints are registered with AzureAD. Only authenticated users can login into the application and all the requests to the API has to pass the token via the header from the frontend services layer.

Lets say there is a route within the application: https://abc.xyz.com/#!/test/100

Now when I open a new browser instance and try the above URL, it asks me to follow all the steps required for AzureAD authentication and navigates me to the landing page:https://xyz.abc.com instead of https://abc.xyz.com/#!/test/100

In this case I am expecting user to be navigated to the requested route : https://abc.xyz.com/#!/test/100 instead of taking him to the landing page: https://abc.xyz.com/ post authentication process.

Can anyone provide their guidance regarding this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points give some idea.

1. AFAIK, the default behavior is  to redirect the user to the original
   page i.e; the redirect url mentioned in the app registration process,
   as microsoft identity basically checks the state whether is protected
   by Azure AD before the location is changed to other path than that.
2. Please check this blog on [Redirect to a custom login page when
   securing your Angular app with MSAL - Waldek Mastykarz](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/redirect-custom-login-page-securing-angular-app-msal/) to try the
   page redirect to the path previews required.
3. You may also try adding another redirect url of that path in azure
   ad portal.